# Test for property access of an abstract or concrete class in Spock

Tags: groovy, mocking, spock

When I mock an abstract or a concrete class with a getter/setter pair and then access the property, the corresponding getter/setter never gets called. However, this works fine if the `Mock` is created for an interface. In the below code, there are 3 sets of two tests each (one testing getter and the other setter) and they are identical except for what they are mocking. The first set works fine because they are testing on the interface, but the next two sets don't:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

interface Foo {
    public String getProp();
    public void setProp(String val);
}
```

```
abstract class FooBase implements Foo {
    public abstract String getProp();
    public abstract void setProp(String val);
}
```

```
class FooImpl extends FooBase {
    public String getProp() {
        println('Foo.getProp')
        return null
    }

    public void setProp(String val) {
        println('Foo.setProp')
    }
}
```

```
class TestPropertyAccess extends Specification {
    def 'test setter on interface'() {
        given:
            def foo = Mock(Foo)
        when:
            foo.prop = 'val'
        then:
            1 * foo.setProp(_)
    }

    def 'test getter on interface'() {
        given:
            def foo = Mock(Foo)
        when:
            foo.prop
        then:
            1 * foo.getProp()
    }

    def 'test setter on abstract'() {
        given:
            def foo = Mock(FooBase)
        when:
            foo.prop = 'val'
            //foo.setProp('val')
        then:
            1 * foo.setProp(_)
            //1 * foo.setProperty('prop', 'val')
    }

    def 'test getter on abstract'() {
        given:
            def foo = Mock(FooBase)
        when:
            foo.prop
            //foo.getProp()
        then:
            1 * foo.getProp()
            //1 * foo.getProperty('prop')
    }

    def 'test setter on concrete'() {
        given:
            def foo = Mock(FooImpl)
        when:
            foo.prop = 'val'
            //foo.setProp('val')
        then:
            1 * foo.setProp(_)
            //1 * foo.setProperty('prop', 'val')
    }

    def 'test getter on concrete'() {
        given:
            def foo = Mock(FooImpl)
        when:
            foo.prop
            //foo.getProp()
        then:
            1 * foo.getProp()
            //1 * foo.getProperty('prop')
    }
}
```

I can get the failing tests to work if I replace the property access with the corresponding getter/setter or if I test for the generic `getProperty`/`setProperty`.

Am I missing something or could this be a spock bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch! I would consider that a Spock bug, given the fact that

- the same code works with dot-property notation when called from a regular Groovy program if you add a real property and make the setter set and the getter get it,
- the test behaves differently in Spock 1.3 and 2.0 preview (there the getter tests work, only the setter tests fail).

Probably something is messed up in the AST transformation generating actual code from the Spock DSL during compilation.

I just opened [bug ticket #1158](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1158) on your behalf.

---

**Update:** Actually I just noticed that if the application classes are implemented in Java, it works as expected, but then of course you cannot use the methods `{get|set}Property` because they are only defined on `GroovyObject`s.

---

**Update 2020-10-28:** The problem is fixed in Spock master and will be part of Spock 2.0. See issue #1158.

Comment: Can using the generic `getProperty` and `setProperty` interactions be a workaround for the two failing test cases in 2.0 preview as well?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I didn't try. For the semantics of those two Groovy-specific methods, please see [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/#_get_setproperty). Please also not my answer update with regard to Java classes.

Comment: "Please also not my answer update with regard to Java classes." -- I am sorry, I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: Read my answer above again, there is a new paragraph called "update".

Comment: **Update:** The problem is fixed in Spock master and will be part of Spock 2.0. See issue #1158.